# Can not write all the data to txt file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with writing data to my .txt file. It doesn't write all the data to my .txt file. I have tried it to put everything in a array, but also that doesn't works.

My code:

```
 BufferedWriter writer = null;

    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -A -o pid");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

              writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(" the path .."));
              writer.write(line);
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        writer.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("Sorry!");
    }
```

It writes only the last line of the console.

Comment: It might be because you recreate the write every time in the loop, along with the file. By default its probably truncating the file and adding the new content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By re-creating the object without closing it during every iteration of the loop, you are discarding what you have written so far (You have to use writer.close() to save what you have written using the object).

You will need to declare **writer** before the loop, so change it to the following

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;

    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -A -o pid");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(" the path .."));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

              writer.write(line);
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        writer.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("Sorry!");
    }
```

Can I just ask, why were you re-declaring the **writer** object every iteration?

Comment: Ah I can see, I have just removed it.